# from webmethod returned two dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webmethod

I have a little problem. From webmethod returned two dimensional array.

My webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[,] Test()
{
string[,] arry1 = new string[2, 2];
arry1[0, 0] = "test00";
arry1[0, 1] = "test01";
arry1[1, 0] = "test10";
arry1[1, 1] = "test11";

return arry1; 
}
```

in my js code im using this way....

```
var arry1=new Array();
$.ajax({
url: "test.aspx/Test",
data: {},
cache: false,
async:false,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
type: "GET",
success: function (data) {
    arry1 = data.d;



},
error: function (response) {
    alert(response);
}
});
alert(arry1[1,1]); //test01  why not test11?
```

How can i do this?

Edit..
Array

```
"test00" "test01";
"test10" "test11";
```

in asp.net

```
arry1[0, 0] = "test00";
arry1[0, 1] = "test01";
arry1[1, 0] = "test10";
arry1[1, 1] = "test11";
```

in javascript

```
arry1[0] // test00
arry1[1] // test01
arry1[2] // test10
arry1[3] // test11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your array running `alert(arry1[1,1]);` would just return the value at position [1](http://jsfiddle.net/8nt3Z/2/) which in the case of JavaScript, is an array, so your result will be `,test01` if you wanted to get `test11`, you would have to do `alert(arry1[3][1]);`, which would get the fourth position in the array `[3]`, and then the value at `[1]` of that array.

```
//What your array might like in JS
var arry1 = [[null,"test00"], [null,"test01"], [null,"test10"], [null,"test11"]];
alert(arry1[1,1]); // test01
alert(arry1[3][1]); // test11
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nt3Z/2/)

Comment: @user3551859: No probs, sorry I only just noticed my fiddle link was messed up, should be okay now if you still want to play around.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, unlike other languages, does have 2D arrays.  Rather, it has arrays of arrays.

That means you need a slightly different syntax

```
alert(arry1[1][1]);
```

Comment: hi. arry1[1][1] alerted only 'e'.-->> t'e'st11

Comment: Then you need to console.log `arry1` and make sure you have what you think you have.